# Limit for non-ephemeral regional public IP per tenant of 1 has been already reached

Tags: load-balancing, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Im trying to create a load balancer in oci but every time it ends with failures and I get this error details in work request "Limit for non-ephemeral regional public IP per tenant of 1 has been already reached". Im on a free tier acoount trying to follow a tutorial and I cant get it to work

I followed the steps in the tutorial